# How can I update mysql database schema in Symfony2

Tags: mysql, symfony, entity, field

Can anybody help me? How can i update mysql database schema (entity, doctrine yml etc) after inserting new integer field type?

I added manually a new field into mysql, I get semantical error like this :

```
       Site\SiteBundle\Entity\Yorum has no field or association named yayin
```

Answer (score 0):

using cmd or a console 
go to the root of the project
and type

php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

and remember to clear up your cache

NOTE: You shouldn't do the changes directly into mysql, add the field into the entity and remember to put the right annotations with the field type, length, etc, when you do the schema:update, that would update the sql schema and you'd probably avoid getting this kind of error messages

Check the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) for more info on this subject

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any relations between two tables?

Because the error

```
  Site\SiteBundle\Entity\Yorum has no field or association named yayin
```

This error is thrown when there is relation between tables